# SQL IF THEN for concatenating fields

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two columns that are `min_price` and `min_price`.  Most of the time, the `min_price` and `max_price` is the same.  Instead of two separate fields for the price, I would like just one "price" field.  If the min_price and the max_price are the same I want to display that price.  If the `min_price` and `max_price` are different, then I would like to show a concatenated string that is (`min_price` "-" `max_price`).  This is just for a table grid, so data types are not important.

Would I use an `IF THEN` statement in my select?

```
select (lots of other stuff), min_price, min_price, (lots more stuff)
```

Not sure where to go from here. I am using MySQL 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
select if(min_price=max_price,min_price,concat(min_price,' - ',max_price)) as price
from your_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the case statement like this:

```
Select case when min_price = max_price then
            min_price
        else
            concat(min_price, '-' , max_price)
        end AS Price
from some_table
```

See here for more info:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN max_price = min_price then cast(min_price as varchar(31)) 
       ELSE cast(min_price as varchar(15) + '-' + cast(max_price as varchar(15) 
       END as Pricew
FROm Some_table
```